# Complexity of select query based on two keys

Tags: database, time-complexity

I'm pretty new to databases, so forgive me if this is a silly question.

I have this query:

```
SELECT* FROM myTable WHERE key1 = value1 AND key2 = value2
```

I think the time complexity of this query is O(log(n)), with "n" the size of myTable, but I'm not sure.
Is it correct or I'm missing something?